# plotly go Scattermapbox is not showing markers

Tags: mapbox, plotly-dash, plotly.graph-objects

I some how have encountered some odd bug. When i try to create a Scattermapbox the markers dont render. This bug came out of no where, It was working perfectly fine then my internet went out and now for the last 8 hours it has not been working.

Ive tried running it in different IDE's
running it in google colab to make sure its not my machine
different data sets.

i am unsure what i have done wrong

The tooltips do display however when i hover over the invisible points.
[image: invisible with tooltips]

and if use the export to png button everything is shown.

[image]

but no matter what it wont show up on the actual map itself and i am at my wits end.

I will include the callback function bellow.

```
@app.callback(
    Output('2dmap','figure'),
    [Input('2dgraph', 'clickData'),
    Input('checklist', 'value')])
def update_map_2d(clickData,checklist):
   
# =============================================================================
#     P1. Render Map when no point is clicked
# =============================================================================
    # If No point has been clicked
    if clickData is None:
        #make a map
        maps2d = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
            lat=[], # set lat and long
            lon=[],
            mode='markers', 
            marker =({'size':5.5}) # make markers size variable 
        ))
    
        # set up map layout
        maps2d.update_layout(
            autosize=True, # Autosize
            hovermode='closest', # Show info on the closest marker
            showlegend=True, # show legend of colors
            mapbox=dict(
                accesstoken=mapbox_access_token, # token
                bearing=0, # starting facing direction
                # starting location
                center=dict(
                    lat=td.cLat,
                    lon=td.cLong
                ),
                #angle and zoom
                pitch=0,
                zoom=12
            ),
            #height and width
            width=1000,
            height=1000
        )
        return maps2d
    else:

       
        xCoord = int(clickData['points'][0]['x'])
        yCoord = int(clickData['points'][0]["y"])
        
        
        
        solutionRow = preatoFrontier.loc[(preatoFrontier['x'] == xCoord)&(preatoFrontier['y'] == yCoord)]

        solId = int(solutionRow['SolId'])

        #solId = 49

        solution = td.getSolution(solutions, solId)       

        color = []
        for row in solution['upGrade']:
            if row == 0:
                color.append('grey')
            if row == 1:
                color.append('green')
            if row == 2:
                color.append('blue')
            if row == 3:
                color.append('red')

        solution['color'] = color
        solution2 = solution[solution['color'].isin(checklist)]
         
        maps2d = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
            lat=solution2['lat'],
            lon=solution2['long'],
            mode='markers', 
            #marker =({'color':solution['color']},{'size':5.5})
            
            marker=dict(
                        size=12,
                        color=solution2['color'], #set color equal to a variable
                        colorscale='Viridis', # one of plotly colorscales
                        showscale=True
                    )

        ))
        
#=============================================================================
# P3. Map Layout
#=============================================================================
        
        #set up map layout
        maps2d.update_layout(
            autosize=False, # Autosize
            hovermode='closest', # Show info on the closest marker
            showlegend=True, # show legend of colors
            mapbox=dict(
                accesstoken=mapbox_access_token, # token
                bearing=0, # starting facing direction
                # starting location
                center=dict(
                    lat=td.cLat,
                    lon=td.cLong
                ),
                #angle and zoom
                pitch=0,
                zoom=10
            ),
            #height and width
            width=1000,
            height=1000
        )

        return maps2d
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of hair pulling, i thought to try creating a new venv and uploading packages one by one and running to see how and where it fails. The last package i installed before it broke was `dash-tools` and sure enough some how that was causing mapbox to bug out hard. So dont install `dash-tools`